# Python way to grab one item from list 1 and assign it four items from list 2?

Tags: python

I have two lists, one with names and one with 4 scores for each player. All I want to do is have a dictionary or tuple (it doesn't matter, whichever would work better) that has the name and the four scores for them.

```
list1 = ['brian', 'lauren', 'bob']
list2 = ['12', '19', '45', '33', '10', '20', 51', '16', '38', '90', '66', '22']
```

the dictionary should look like:

```
finalDict = {"brian": 12, 19, 45, 33, "lauren": 10, 20, 51, 16, ect.}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far :)

Comment: Edit your question, don't add the code in a comment

Comment: can't seem to get use to this comment section the way the "enter" key works. basically I know I need some type of "for" loop that iterates through both lists like: for item in list1, list2: dict = {list1[0], list2[0,3]} and so on

Comment: @Kosmot199 That sounds like a good place to start.

Comment: Now i did just edit the code partially and I did figure out how to assign the list of names into a dictionary as the keys, but I temporarily put zeros. It prints out as info = {'brian':0, 'lauren':0, 'bob':0}

Comment: @Kosmot199 If only there were some way you could [slice](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) a list into smaller pieces ;-).

Comment: Ok, I see where you're going, but could you show me an example of how to grab the first four, append them as values to the first key, then the following four for the second value?

Comment: @Kosmot199 I would really like to suggest a book http://www.diveintopython.net/toc/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_scores(names, scores):
    x, y, results = a_number, another_number, {}
    for name in names:
        results[name] = scores[y:x]
        x, y = x + an_amount, y + some_amount
    return results
```

This should get you started. `a_number`, `another_number`, `an_amount` and `some_amount` are place holders. I'll leave you to figure out what they should be. Some keywords for this example [tuple assignment](http://robert-lujo.com/post/40871820711/python-destructuring) and [list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation).

Comment: Thank you very much! This made much more sense the way you did this versus how I was attempting this. I'll also be sure to check out that book you suggested.

Comment: @Kosmot199 If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as the solution so other who may have your problem will know it helps. It also gives the answer-er credit for spending time to help out :)

Comment: @Parker, thanks for the reminder. I'm still trying to get use to this website even though I've been programming for quite some time and have come here a lot.